# where is the mistake in my script?

Tags: php

Friends, what is the problem in my php multifile uploading script? When running this script, it do nothing!! please help me to find out the mistake.
Thanks in advance..Here is the html code..

```
    <form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h3>Upload your files here <small>(1GB max)</small> ..</h3>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    <br>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file">
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload file(s)" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

And here is the "upload.php " file..

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
    //upload and rename file 
    $filename=$_FILES["file"]["name"];
    $tmp_filename=$_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $count_tmp_filename=count($tmp_filename);
    for($i = 0; $i < $count_tmp_filename; $i++){ 
        $file_basename = substr($filename[$i], 0, strripos($filename[$i], '.'));
        $file_ext = substr($filename[$i], strripos($filename[$i], '.'));
        $filesize = $_FILES["file"]["size"][$i];
        $allowed_file_types = array('.doc','.docx','.rtf','.pdf','.jpg','.png','.mp4','.mp3');
        if (in_array($file_ext,$allowed_file_types) && ($filesize < 1000000000000)) { 
        // Rename file 
            $newfilename = 'droidsolve_'.$file_basename.$file_ext;
            if (file_exists("upload/" . $newfilename)) {
                // file already exists 
                error echo "You have already uploaded this file.";
            } else{ 
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$tmp_filename[$i]], "upload/" . $newfilename);
                echo "File uploaded successfully.";
            }
        }
    }
} 
?>
```

Comment: This is unreadable. Edit your question.

Comment: Please format your code more carefully.

Comment: How ? I dont know that.. I am New here.please help me to do that

Comment: In the future please format yourself, take a look at this thread if you have issues, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks.

Comment: You can't have the same `name` attribute for multiple elements. You could turn it into an array `name="file[]"`. http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Comment: I have tried it. But it says undefined inedx in line 58.

Answer (score 1):

As chris85 pointed out in the comments a name is unique in a form set. So change your code either to (leave out one of the file inputs):

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h3>Upload your files here <small>(1GB max)</small> ..</h3>
<br>
<br>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file">
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Upload file(s)" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

Or to (making it an array and adjust the `id`s):

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<h3>Upload your files here <small>(1GB max)</small> ..</h3>
<br>
<br>
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file1">
<br>
<input type="file" name="file[]" id="file2">
<br>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Upload file(s)" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

With the latter you will need to change your PHP upload code accordingly (e.g. with a `foreach` loop).

Comment: I can't it. Can you give me an modified upload.php?

Comment: You might be better looking here for a [freelancer](http://freelancer.com) or update your question with a new error message :-)